# Mysql date between two dates in average interval per seconds

Tags: php, mysql

I have one table which have number of records entered on exact time in field add_date.
add_date might have

```
"2012-08-25 01:10:12" 
"2012-08-25 01:10:13"
"2012-08-25 01:20:13"
"2012-08-25 01:21:12"
"2012-08-25 01:23:52"
"2012-08-25 01:23:56"
```

So, I want only those records which have not same minute in search
my sql query is

```
$sdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date." ".$stime));
$edate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date." ".$etime));
select add_date, speed from tbl_track where DATEadd_date BETWEEN '".$sdate."' AND '".$edate."' and item=(some item)
```

date part will be same but time part is in range like morning 10 to evening 8
I want

```
"2012-08-25 01:10:13"
"2012-08-25 01:20:13"
"2012-08-25 01:21:12"
"2012-08-25 01:23:56"
```

minute is different but same minute can not be in result minutes must be unique

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like

```
 select distinct(date_format(add_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i")) ...
```

or

```
 selec date_format(add_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") as datemins ... group by datemins
```

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, but this returns date in different format, it do not removes same date time from other, result is same...